# Magento 2 How to do export products csv & xml from admin end?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, products, export, custom-button

I would like to implement **export** catalog products functionality from admin end from custom module.

I have followed below steps for displaying export button at admin end catalog > products but unable to export products data in the form of csv/xml/xls.

1. Created custom module `Vendor_Employee`.
2. app/code/Vendor/Employee/view/adminhtml/ui_component/`product_listing.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
   <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing_data_source</item>
       </item>
   </argument>
   <settings>
       <spinner>product_columns</spinner>
       <deps>
           <dep>product_listing.product_listing_data_source</dep>
       </deps>
   </settings>
   <dataSource name="product_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
       <settings>
           <storageConfig>
               <param name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters.store_id</param>
           </storageConfig>
           <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
       </settings>
       <aclResource>Magento_Catalog::products</aclResource>
       <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider" name="product_listing_data_source">
           <settings>
               <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
               <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
           </settings>
       </dataProvider>
   </dataSource>
   <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
       <settings>
           <sticky>true</sticky>
       </settings>
       <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
       <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
       <filters name="listing_filters">
           <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
               <settings>
                   <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                   <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                   <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                   <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
               </settings>
           </filterSelect>
       </filters>
       <massaction name="listing_massaction"
                   component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions"
                   class="\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
           <action name="delete">
               <settings>
                   <confirm>
                       <message translate="true">Delete selected items?</message>
                       <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                   </confirm>
                   <url path="catalog/product/massDelete"/>
                   <type>delete</type>
                   <label translate="true">Delete1</label>
               </settings>
           </action>
           <action name="status">
               <settings>
                   <type>status</type>
                   <label translate="true">Change status1</label>
                   <actions>
                       <action name="0">
                           <type>enable</type>
                           <label translate="true">Enable</label>
                           <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                               <param name="status">1</param>
                           </url>
                       </action>
                       <action name="1">
                           <type>disable</type>
                           <label translate="true">Disable1</label>
                           <url path="catalog/product/massStatus">
                               <param name="status">2</param>
                           </url>
                       </action>
                   </actions>
               </settings>
           </action>
           <action name="attributes">
               <settings>
                   <url path="catalog/product_action_attribute/edit"/>
                   <type>attributes</type>
                   <label translate="true">Update attributes</label>
               </settings>
           </action>
       </massaction>
       <paging name="listing_paging"/>

       <!-- Added Export Button Here -->

       <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                           <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToCsv</item>
                       </item>
                       <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                           <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToXml</item>
                       </item>
                       <item name="xls" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xls</item>
                           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XLS</item>
                           <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToXls</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </exportButton>
    <!-- Added Export Button Here -->

   </listingToolbar>
   <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <settings>
           <childDefaults>
               <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.actions</item>
                   <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                   <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                       <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                   </item>
               </param>
           </childDefaults>
       </settings>
       <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="0">
           <settings>
               <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
           </settings>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="10">
           <settings>
               <filter>textRange</filter>
               <label translate="true">ID</label>
               <sorting>asc</sorting>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="thumbnail" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Thumbnail" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail" sortOrder="20">
           <settings>
               <altField>name</altField>
               <hasPreview>1</hasPreview>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <label translate="true">Thumbnail</label>
               <sortable>false</sortable>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
           <settings>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <filter>text</filter>
               <label translate="true">Name</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="type_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="40">
           <settings>
               <options class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type"/>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Type</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="attribute_set_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
           <settings>
               <options class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options"/>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Attribute Set</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="sku" sortOrder="60">
           <settings>
               <filter>text</filter>
               <label translate="true">SKU</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="price" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price" sortOrder="70">
           <settings>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <filter>textRange</filter>
               <label translate="true">Price</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="visibility" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="80">
           <settings>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <options class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility"/>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Visibility</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="90">
           <settings>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <options class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status"/>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Status</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <column name="websites" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Websites" sortOrder="100">
           <settings>
               <addField>true</addField>
               <options class="Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Collection"/>
               <dataType>text</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Websites</label>
           </settings>
       </column>
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions" sortOrder="200">
           <settings>
               <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
           </settings>
       </actionsColumn>
   </columns>
   ```
3. app/code/Vendor/Employee/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/GridToCsv.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Employee\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;
   use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
   use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
   use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
   class gridToCsv extends Action
   {

   public function execute()
   {
           //csv
           $this->_view->loadLayout(false);
           $fileName = 'catalog_products.csv';
           $exportBlock = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid');
           $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
           $this->_fileFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
           return $this->_fileFactory->create(
               $fileName,
               $exportBlock->getCsvFile(),
               DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
           );

   }
   }
   ```

[image]

Here i am able to export only few columns but not all Please advise?

Comment: have you get any solution for that?

Comment: No @DharmendraJadav

Comment: Getting any solution ??

Comment: still not found the solutions RK Rathod

Answer (score 2):

**Below Is a Default Class it only Export that Data which are show in your Admin Grid not Export your whole data**

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
```

**If you  want all Data you have create a Custom Export  Button that export your all data.**

edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add Button into Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">

    <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>

    <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>

</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you define in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and See your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: can you give a full code ???

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in grid/listing xml you need to add "**selectProvider**" item to exportButton node.
In your case:

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">
                    product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.ids
                </item>
                <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToCsv</item>
                </item>
                <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToXml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="xls" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xls</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XLS</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">employee/export/gridToXls</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

The controller seems to be okay, but to be sure check the OOB exporter :

> **\Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToCsv**

If the problem is in exporter, try to extend from the OOB one.